# JMeter wrong parsing arguments

Tags: jmeter

I am struggling with wrong parsing arguments in JMeter.

I have some tests and I need to generate random string with passed length.

So.. I call my jmeter like this:

```
jmeter -t C:\Users\patryk\Desktop\webSocketTest.jmx -JRequests=1 -JDataLen=1 -JUsers=1
```

My User defined variables look like this:
[image: User Def variables]

My JSR223 Sampler has code:

```
def myVar ="${__RandomString(${dataLength},abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ)}"
log.info("the text is: " + myVar)
vars.put("generatedData",myVar);
```

and then I  use it in body of SignalR request:
[image]

After I run my script i got errors like this:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1 "
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_371]
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_371]
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_371]
    at org.apache.jmeter.functions.RandomString.execute(RandomString.java:74) ~[ApacheJMeter_functions.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.util.CompoundVariable.execute(CompoundVariable.java:138) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.util.CompoundVariable.execute(CompoundVariable.java:113) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.FunctionProperty.getStringValue(FunctionProperty.java:91) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.testbeans.TestBeanHelper.unwrapProperty(TestBeanHelper.java:129) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.testbeans.TestBeanHelper.prepare(TestBeanHelper.java:84) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.notifyTestListenersOfStart(StandardJMeterEngine.java:215) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.run(StandardJMeterEngine.java:396) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_371]
```

So it indicates that my passed argument is "1 " not "1" but we can clearly see in command that's not true! What can be wrong? Everything works if i use hardcoded values of passed variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't inline [JMeter Functions or Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) into Groovy scripts.

[Explanation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler):

> The JSR223 test elements have a feature (compilation) that can significantly increase performance. To benefit from this feature:
>
> - Use Script files instead of inlining them. This will make JMeter compile them if this feature is available on ScriptEngine and cache them.
> - Or Use Script Text and check Cache compiled script if available property.
>
>   When using this feature, ensure your script code does not use JMeter variables or JMeter function calls directly in script code as **caching would only cache first replacement**. Instead use script parameters.

So the options are in:

1. Either use [__Random()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) function directly in the Sampler body
2. Or generate the random data anywhere else and provide `generatedData` as third argument:

   ```
   ${__RandomString(${dataLength},abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ,generatedData)}
   ```
3. Or replace first line of your Groovy script with the following expression:

   ```
   def myVar = org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(vars.get('dataLength') as int)
   ```

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)

Comment: Thank you Dmitri! Your answer works in my case, and of course your explanation is very valuable!